# как создать многомерный массив в SWIFT

Tags: массивы, swift, xcode, arraylist

```
elements['key1']=['qwe1','asd1','zxc1']
elements['key2']=['qwe2','asd2','zxc2']
elements['key3']=['qwe3','asd3','zxc3']
```

**Цель**: создать массив elements, где ключами являются текстовые значения. Каждый элемент массива состоит из N-значений (в примере 3, но планируется больше). Необходимо обращаться к массиву и получать значение, например делаю запрос elements['key1'][2] и получаю zxc1

**Вопрос**: как правильно в Swift создать такой массив (xcode дает ошибку) или может кто предложить какой метод/решение

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать словарь:

```
import UIKit


var emptyDictionary = [String: [String]]()
var testArray = [String]()

for i in 1...9 {
    testArray.append(i.description)
    
    if i == 9{
        for j in 0...4{
            emptyDictionary["key_\(emptyDictionary.count)"] = testArray
        }
    }
}
```

таким образом вы сможете складывать в массив сколько угодно значений, и каждый массив будет иметь уникальный ключ:

```
print(emptyDictionary)
print(emptyDictionary["key_3"]?[0].description)
```

---

```
["key_4": ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"], "key_0": ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"], "key_3": ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"], "key_1": ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"], "key_2": ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]]
Optional("1")
```

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145023/discussion-on-answer-by-andrew------swift); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.